# Cannot start NextJS with Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, next.js

I created a new project written in Next JS,

When opening the browser with an IP and PORT such as "http://127.0.0.1:4321/" it works.
attached image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1h2D.png).

But when I try to connect to it with Nginx through an IP and Route such as "http://127.0.0.1/nextjs/" I get errors.
attached image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjtJG.png).

The NextJS code is the code you get at the start of a project without changes.

This is the Nginx configuration.

```
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }       
        
    location /nextjs/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4321/;
    }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

I tried to add this code to next.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/nextjs',
  assetPrefix: '/nextjs/',
}
```

And this does not worked for me.

Note: All this on a Linux server.